# Twitter Bootstrap Collapse plugin Direction—Horizontal instead of Vertical

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to collapse the the Bootstrap Collapse plugin from horizontally instead of vertically? Looking at the code this ability doesn't seem to be built in, but I'm hoping I'm just missing something...

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured out how to do this very easily without modifying or adding any javascript.

First you define the following CSS after all Twitter Bootstrap CSS:

```
.collapse {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

.collapse.height {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
  transition: height 0.35s ease;
}

.collapse.width {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
  transition: width 0.35s ease;
}

.collapse.in.width {
  width: auto;
}

.collapse.in.height {
  height: auto;
}
```

Next, on the target element (where you define the `.collapse` class) you need to add the class `.width` or `.height` depending on what property you want to animate.

Finally, you **must** wrap the contents of the target element and explicitly define its width if animating the width. This is not required if animating the height.

You can find a working example here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/ZBAHS/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843732/bootstrap-3-0-collapse-horizontally-bounces-in-chrome/26898065 and http://jsfiddle.net/zu5ftdjx/ for a working example

Comment: Updated working Bootply for 3.3.7 => https://www.bootply.com/vwS8HxEeVB

Comment: This didn't work in the latest 3.x or 4.x -- see my update here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44070096/171456

Answer (score 22):

With bootstrap 3.0.0, you just need to add the width class to the target element and then the following css if you want it to animate.

```
.collapse.width {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    transition: width 0.35s ease;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had originally used Roy Daniels's version above and was looking to see if there was a simpler way of doing it in 3.0 now we've upgraded.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using flat-ui on top of bootstrap.

Comment: Is there a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 9):

***Updated 2019***

**Bootstrap 4.x**

Bootstrap 4 horizontal collapse transition is basically the same, expected the visible class is now `.show` instead of `.in`. It also may help to specify display:block since many elements are now display: flex.

```
.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

[4.x horizontal collapse demo](http://codeply.com/go/UiteY92ke8/bootstrap-4-horizontal-collapse)
[4.x sidebar demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/8ESO56VMns)

Also see:
[Bootstrap horizontal menu collapse to sidemenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49527465/bootstrap-horizontal-menu-collapse-to-sidemenu/49535297#49535297)
[How to slide nav bar from left instead from top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31641352/bootstrap-how-to-slide-nav-bar-from-left-instead-from-top/55260765#55260765)

---

**Bootstrap 3.3.7** (original answer)

None of the existing answers worked for me. To make the collapse animation horizontal in the latest versions you need to set both transition to width, and also use **visibility**.

```
.collapse {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.collapse.in {
  visibility: visible;
}
.collapsing {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: height, visibility;
  transition-property: height, visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.35s;
  transition-duration: 0.35s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.collapsing.width {
  -webkit-transition-property: width, visibility;
  transition-property: width, visibility;
  width: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

[3.x demo](http://codeply.com/go/8I0FglhMdP/bootstrap-horizontal-collapse)

Comment: How to make it horizontal accordion like in vertical and opening one at a time?

Comment: I have something working based on this example, but when the element is collapsing horizontally I'm seeing word wrapping.  I don't see anything that prevents it in these examples, what am I missing?

Comment: @MikeFlynn  the demo links seem to for me but either way the relevant CSS is in the answer

Answer (score 6):

In my version of bootstrap 3 (using LESS), I simply had to include this in my global less file:

```
.collapsing.width  { 
    width: 0;
    height: auto;
    .transition(width 0.35s ease);
}
```

The extra class *has* to be `width` since the collapse.js looks for this class for the transition.  I tried everyone else's suggestions, but they didn't work for me.

Comment: This worked for me, but since my less file is not compiled together with bootstrap, I had to define the `.transition` mixin before using it: ``.transition (@transition) {
  -webkit-transition: @transition;  
  -moz-transition:    @transition;
  -ms-transition:     @transition; 
  -o-transition:      @transition;  
}``

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't appear to be an option for that particular plugin. It looks like you may need to modify it or hook into it somehow to get it to work that way...

After looking at the JS file for a bit I noticed a couple things. First thing is that it looks like it might be using **bootstrap-transition.js** ,which appears to be using CSS3 transitions. So it might be possible to write a new transition. I am not 100% certain if that is how it is working though.

**Option One**

My suggestion would be to either poke around in the bootstrap-collapse.js plugin file for a while and see if you can figure out how it is working.

In particular I would look at this part... **bootstrap-carousel.js**

```
this.$element[dimension](0)
this.transition('addClass', $.Event('show'), 'shown')
$.support.transition && this.$element[dimension](this.$element[0][scroll])
```

It looks like `.transition` is a callback from **bootstrap-transition.js**

**Option Two**

My second suggestion would be to just write something of your own.

**My Answer**

And finally my answer is that from looking at the bootstrap documentation it doesn't appear to be an option.

**Some additional info:**

This website seems to be doing similar stuff with CSS3 transitions.
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking too. It'd be nice to leverage what's already in Bootstrap, so I think I'm going to try creating my own transition leveraging bootstrap-transition.js. Thanks for your input. I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem.. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 1):

i think translateX(-100%) and translateX(0) might be the way to go rather than animating width as uses hardware acceleration correctly when supported

Answer (score 0):

Good answers here, but I had to make some modifications for a cleaner, two-way transition:

```
.collapse.width, .collapsing {
    height: 25px; /* depending on your element height */
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.25s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.25s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.25s ease;
    transition: width 0.25s ease;
}
```

Setting a fixed height also helped prevent page "jump" as the element collapsed and expanded.