# Accordion of left to right Bootstrap 4 is possible?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there any way to arrange the Bootstrap accordion horizontally (from left to right) instead of top down?

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

[image]

Comment: Try this one in bootstrap 3, maybe it can work with 4 too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749361/bootstrap-3-collapse-left-to-right

Comment: What did you alreay try? Show some code.