# Button toggle horizontal with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a button to expand/collapse horizontally other elements(share buttons) and inline using the bootstrap framework

I'm failing at two things:

1. The button doesn't expand the other elements inline and after the actual + button
2. When it collapse back the elements in it breaks the line and stack on top of each other

I prepared a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/g7qCZ/

Here is my html code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">+</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse in width" style="background-color:yellow;">
    <div style="padding: 0; overflow:hidden;">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my css:

```css
#demo.width {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    transition: width 0.35s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> 1) The button doesn't expand the other elements inline and after the actual + button

That's because the 'other elements' are nested inside of a `div` element.  Div is a block level element with the default of `display: block`.  You have to override this to `display: inline-block` if you would like the div contents to appear on the same line as your plus button.

> 2) When it collapse back the elements in it breaks the line and stack on top of each other

Overflowing is the last resort for a browser.  It would rather not when there are better alternatives and typically wrapping is a better alternative.  So the browser will first try to wrap the elements.  Only once it can't anymore will it use utilize `overflow: hidden` to hide the elements.  In order to tell the browser not to wrap, you can use `white-space: nowrap;`

---

#### What to do instead:

[Bootstrap collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) is best suited for collapsing vertically.  In order to collapse horizontally, you'll have to do a little bit of work.  You can use [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to toggle the width property.  However, this will decrement the width in JavaScript which is less performant than straight CSS3 transitions.

Here's another approach.  Build a data toggle that just toggles the class `in`.  Then style the control to have zero width by default, and make it full width when `in` is applied:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
        data-toggle="toggle" data-target="#demo">+</button>
```

```js
$("[data-toggle='toggle']").click(function() {
    var selector = $(this).data("target");
    $(selector).toggleClass('in');
});
```

```css
#demo {
    width: 0px;
}
#demo.in {
    width: 220px;
}
```

Then you can set up the rest of the styles on your demo div:

```css
#demo {
    -webkit-transition: width 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 2s ease;
    -o-transition: width 2s ease;
    transition: width 2s ease;

    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

### [Here's a working demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/S9hhP/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: that's brilliant! Thanks so much for the in-detail explanation! I have one more question. How would I make this re-usable in a page where I would have multiple share boxes like the example?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @KyleMit works well. I think you should indeed use the `white-space: nowrap;` and  `display: inline-block` (or `float:left`) to solve your issues.

You can apply both properties mentioned above on your `#demo`:

```
#demo {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

For everything else you can use only Bootstrap code <strike>and do not need jQuery animate</strike>. Some fixes for Bootstrap are required, see https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15104, [Bootstrap 3.0 Collapse Horizontally - Bounces in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843732/bootstrap-3-0-collapse-horizontally-bounces-in-chrome/2689806).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1agh7kaf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since 5.1 Bootstrap supports [.collapse-horizontal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/collapse/#horizontal)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).