# Best practice - Change animation on bootstrap mobile menu from dropdown (slideDown) to slideIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm looking for a best practice to change the animation effect on mobile menu from slidedown to slidein.

I want to have the menu sliding in from left to right (filling about 70% of the viewport, overlay on top of the screen). I do not want the facebook effect sliding the content when the menu arrives. I only want that menu overlay on top of the content.

What's the best way to do this?

Link to jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3819/

```
      <!-- Static navbar -->
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown this-works">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Works <b class="caret"></b></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-form">
              <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="InputSearch" class="form-control">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">GO</button>
                          </span>
                      </div><!-- /input-group -->
                  </form>
              </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown this-doesnt">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Broken <b class="caret"></b></i></a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-form">
              <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" id="InputSearch" class="form-control">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                              <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">GO</button>
                          </span>
                      </div><!-- /input-group -->
                  </form>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the menu code you're using now? Or recreate it with [Bootply](http://bootply.com)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3819/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12498476/2454790